# Segmented mp4 in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm have pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/cam ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux fragment-duration=10000 streamable=1 ! multifilesink next-file=2 location=file-%03d.mp4
```

The first segment is played well, others not. When I'm try to view the structure of damaged mp4 see an interesting bug:

1. MOOV
2. Some data
3. MOOF
4. MDAT
5. MOOF
6. MDAT

The most interesting thing in "Some data". There is no header data, they simply exist. By block size I think it MDAT. I find size of the block and add before it MDAT header. File immediately becomes valid and playing. But the unknown piece can't be played because before it no MOOF header.

Problem is at mp4mux and qtmux. Tested on GStreamer 1.1.0 and 1.2.2. All results are identical.

Can use multifilesink not correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you take look at documentation for [`multifilesink`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multifilesink.html) you will find the answer:

> It is not possible to use this element to create independently playable mp4 files, use the splitmuxsink element for that instead. ...

So use [`splitmuxsink`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-splitmuxsink.html) and don't forget to send EOS when you done to correct finish last file

**Update**

Looks like at time when question has been asked there wasn't such element like `splitmuxsink`

Comment: @Vladimir `splitmuxsink` appeared in [gstreamer 1.6](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/1.6/). And yes, `splitmuxsink` is your friend. The OP's pipeline then reduces to `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/cam ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=file-%03d.mp4`. No need to specify the mp4mux, it is the default for `splitmuxsink`.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be reproduced using videotestsrc instead of rtsp?

Try replacing your h264 receiving and depayloading with "videotestsrc num-buffers= ! x264enc ! mp4mux ..."

This might be a bug, please file it at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer so it gets proper attention from maintainers.

Also, how are you trying to play it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.

I tried to use videotestsrc but result the same. I don't understand how fragment-duration works with multifilesink.

Play through vlc. Also for tests converts with ffmpeg.

Damaged atoms are after MOOV: [Screen](http://d.pr/i/ZHfh+)

Comment: from a quick try here I can see that there is a warning on multifilesink not being seekable. This is definitely an issue for generating those fragments correctly. Please file a bug about your scenario so this multifilesink issue can be fixed and/or any other bug related to it.